# DataGridTextColumn not accepting decimal place WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My datagridtextcolumn is bound to a float property, however, in the UI it doesn't let me type the decimal place, i.e. I want to type 2.3 but it ignores the decimal place i'm typing and just has 23.

Is there something wrong I'm doing?

**The XAML is:**

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.lab}" MinWidth="80" 
    x:Name="FoncValue" 
    Width="*" 
    Binding="{Binding FValue, Mode=TwoWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}"
    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource dataGridNumericnLimit}"
/>
```

Property is `public float FValue`

@Andy this is the error message that comes up when `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is removed:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '1.55adsad' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=FValue; DataItem='ConModel' (HashCode=64331281); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseSingle(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

Comment: Remove UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,

Comment: also needs to be able to be set from the property itself and reflected on the UI, so this isn't an option

Comment: That is mode=twoway you're describing so take UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged out and watch it work.

Comment: hmm it works... my understanding of how it works must be wrong.... why does this work? (it does btw, thanks)

Comment: actually... it doesn't work in the sense it now lets you type characters.... so it doesn't work :\

Comment: This would be validation. Different thing entirely. An invalid entry will not transfer to a bound decimal though.

Comment: Yeah I'm just thinking if we say let someone type "1.3asd2fasd" and then tabbed away, there needs to be validation at that point. Not sure how that is done

Comment: If it's bound to a double that'll fail to transfer and you're left with a bad string in the cell but doesn't it light up with a red border by default?  You can limit text input with a behavior. I'll go look for the one I use.

Comment: That's fine that it fails to transfer... but then how do we get it to show the actual value of the property in that case? It does indeed come up with a red border... unless we just wait for someone to correct it? doing this also causes the UI to freeze with the following message - see update

Comment: I added the behavior to my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222414/discussion-between-sushi7777-and-andy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is because binding on the textbox text property is twoway.

You are typing in a textbox.

```
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

Makes each letter you type transfer from the view as you type it. This then goes to the bound double and back to the UI. Which formats your number.

There are several ways round this.

The first is to let the user type the whole number before it is transferred to the viewmodel. You do that by removing  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

An alternative is to set

```
FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
```

This is intended to return functionality back to an older version of the framework. You will find some quirks though, which may or may not be significant to you.

Another is more of a hack and is to set Delay="1000" on the binding. This allows the user to type that decimal place and a number after it before the decimal place transfers.

Your have several validation options.

You could, for example, use a validationRule on the binding.

To limit input you could use or base your own behavior on the below. I thought I may have copied this off a SO myself but I can't find the thread just now.

```
public class TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public string EmptyValue { get; set; } = "0";

    public double Minimum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));


    public double Maximum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(10.0));



    public int MaxInteger
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MaxIntegerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxIntegerProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxIntegerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaxInteger", typeof(int), typeof(TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(1));



    public int MaxDecimals
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MaxDecimalsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxDecimalsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxDecimalsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaxDecimals", typeof(int), typeof(TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(2));



    /// <summary>
    ///     Attach our behaviour. Add event handlers
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput += PreviewTextInputHandler;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += PreviewKeyDownHandler;
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(AssociatedObject, PastingHandler);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Deattach our behaviour. remove event handlers
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput -= PreviewTextInputHandler;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= PreviewKeyDownHandler;
        DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(AssociatedObject, PastingHandler);
    }

    void PreviewTextInputHandler(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        string text;
        if (this.AssociatedObject.Text.Length < this.AssociatedObject.CaretIndex)
            text = this.AssociatedObject.Text;
        else
        {
            //  Remaining text after removing selected text.
            string remainingTextAfterRemoveSelection;

            text = TreatSelectedText(out remainingTextAfterRemoveSelection)
                ? remainingTextAfterRemoveSelection.Insert(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart, e.Text)
                : AssociatedObject.Text.Insert(this.AssociatedObject.CaretIndex, e.Text);
        }

        e.Handled = !ValidateText(text);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     PreviewKeyDown event handler
    /// </summary>
    void PreviewKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.EmptyValue))
        {
            return;
        }


        string text = null;

        // Handle the Backspace key
        if (e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            if (!this.TreatSelectedText(out text))
            {
                if (AssociatedObject.SelectionStart > 0)
                    text = this.AssociatedObject.Text.Remove(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart - 1, 1);
            }
        }
        // Handle the Delete key
        else if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            // If text was selected, delete it
            if (!this.TreatSelectedText(out text) && this.AssociatedObject.Text.Length > AssociatedObject.SelectionStart)
            {
                // Otherwise delete next symbol
                text = this.AssociatedObject.Text.Remove(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart, 1);
            }
        }

        if (text == string.Empty)
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.Text = this.EmptyValue;
            if (e.Key == Key.Back)
                AssociatedObject.SelectionStart++;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void PastingHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            string text = Convert.ToString(e.DataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text));

            if (!ValidateText(text))
                e.CancelCommand();
        }
        else
            e.CancelCommand();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Validate certain text by our regular expression and text length conditions
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"> Text for validation </param>
    /// <returns> True - valid, False - invalid </returns>
    private bool ValidateText(string text)
    {
        double number;
        if (!Double.TryParse(text, out number))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (number < Minimum)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (number > Maximum)
        {
            return false;
        }
        int dotPointer = text.IndexOf('.');
        // No point entered so the decimals must be ok
        if(dotPointer == -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (dotPointer > MaxInteger)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(text.Substring(dotPointer +1).Length > MaxDecimals)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Handle text selection
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true if the character was successfully removed; otherwise, false. </returns>
    private bool TreatSelectedText(out string text)
    {
        text = null;
        if (AssociatedObject.SelectionLength <= 0)
            return false;

        var length = this.AssociatedObject.Text.Length;
        if (AssociatedObject.SelectionStart >= length)
            return true;

        if (AssociatedObject.SelectionStart + AssociatedObject.SelectionLength >= length)
            AssociatedObject.SelectionLength = length - AssociatedObject.SelectionStart;

        text = this.AssociatedObject.Text.Remove(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart, AssociatedObject.SelectionLength);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Shooting}"
                             ToolTip="A number representing the lethality of effect when shooting"
                             
                             >
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ui:TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour MaxDecimals="1" 
                                                             MaxInteger="3" 
                                                             Minimum="{StaticResource Zero}" 
                                                             Maximum="{StaticResource Hundred}" />
                            <ui:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBox>
```

And

```
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                Path=Content.Text}" TextAlignment="Right">
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <ui:TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour MaxDecimals="2" 
                                                                 MaxInteger="1" 
                                                                 Minimum="{StaticResource Zero}" 
                                                                 Maximum="{StaticResource Ten}" />
                                <ui:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior/>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </TextBox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
```

As an aside.

I would advise against allowing a user to edit in a datagrid unless your requirements are very simple.

As soon as you want to do anything like validation you start hitting complications.

I usually make datagrids read only and the user chooses a row, edits in a separate panel. They then have to choose to commit or abandon their changes explicitly.  This gives a fixed path for validation and they edit a clone of the data until it's validated and committed.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Do you have a line of XAML to show how you're using it? I'm assuming this is obviously still with the update propertychanged line out which is fine. I've not used validation rules but I've used behaviours.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I think because of how the UI was designed i.e. how others wanted it to work, I had to sacrifice doing it the sensible way you suggested and tried to cram all validation into the cell of the datagrid row. In my original question, I've set my editing element style. I am assuming I can use the second part of the XAML you wrote within that? Would putting it inside the editing element style work/be appropriate?

Comment: Yes. Edit template. That xaml above is pasted from an unusual piece of UI where there's effectively a matrix of data being edited so all cells have the same behavior. https://i.imgur.com/d7iucI8.png

Comment: Nice. Applying this is proving to be difficult though as I don't want this to apply to every cell, I've already got a cellstyle set across all cells, but only 2 cells are numerical like the one I posted... I tried applying it only to the TextBox in a style but now I'm bumping into issues like I can't put a behaviour in a style... so this should be fun...